# rm command not working

Tags: command-line, mount, permissions, ntfs, rm

I'm trying to delete some broken video driver files from a Windows partition on a dual boot environment (that's preventing Windows to start, event on recovery mode).

After mounting the partition I did :

```
cd /media/anderson/F47891047890C720/Windows/System32/drivers
rm sisagpx.sys
```

but that produced no error and the files are still there, as I could check with 
 `ls sisagpx.sys` command output:

```
sisagpx.sys sisraid2.sys sisraid4.sys
```

I'm a newbie, but I think the mount is not readonly. I got some error regarding this, but remounted with:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/anderson/F47891047890C720
```

Regading permissions, `ls -f sisagpx.sys` gives me the following:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 anderson anderson 58400 set  5  2015 sisagpx.sys
```

while `ls -ld .` give me this:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 anderson anderson 65536 abr 23 19:51 .
```

So, I think I should be able to delete the file.
Don't know what else to try. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Try: sudo rm -rf sisagpx.sys

Comment: It's strange that there are no errors from `rm`. Is your `rm` aliased to `rm -f` by any chance? Show us output of `type -a rm`.

Comment: @ramsudharsan `rm -rf` didn't work. It shows no error, but does nothing, just like before.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `rm is /bin/rm`

Comment: Can you check if this file is re-created every time by using `ls` with `-i` option before and after running `rm` command and pasting the results here? One more thing: after runing `rm` command type `echo $?` - if `rm` really succeeded then `0` should be printed.

Comment: It displays the same output before and after `rm`: `4111 -rwxrwxrwx 1 anderson anderson 58400 set  5  2015 sisagpx.sys`

Comment: ok, how about `$?`?

Comment: and `file /bin/rm`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57694/discussion-between-anderson-pimentel-and-arkadiusz-drabczyk).

Comment: Try to get rid of the file in a different way: `sudo mv /media/anderson/F47891047890C720/Windows/System32/drivers/sisagpx.sys /dev/null`. Will move the file to the void. **Make sure the path is well written first**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57694/discussion-between-anderson-pimentel-and-arkadiusz-drabczyk), the reason was that `NTFS` filesystem in question has been dirty and contained cached metadata. An attempt to re-mount it resulted in:

```
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Failed to daemonize.
Version 2016.2.22AR.1 integrated FUSE 28
Mounted /dev/sda2 (Read-Only, label "", NTFS 3.1)
Cmdline options:
Mount options: allow_other,nonempty,relatime,ro,fsname=/dev/sda2,blkdev,blksize=4096
Ownership and permissions disabled, configuration type 7
```

After fixing it with
[ntsfix](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ntfsfix.8.html)
OP was able to remove the file.

Comment: Thanks for the great help! I was able to delete the file and everything worked!